# How can I quickly view a list of application-specific keyboard shortcuts on all operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux)?

Tags: windows, linux, osx, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a standalone program or OS utility that will quickly list an application's keyboard shortcuts to help teach digital fluency.

I haven't quite found any individual programs or utilities that allow a user to quickly see the available keyboard shortcuts that are registered in the application they are currently using such as an internet browser, word processor, or IDE for example. The closest program I've found is a MacOS program called ["CheatSheet"](https://mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) which will list each shortcut listed in the menu bar.

[image: CheatSheet on MacOS]

I'd like to take any arbitrary application on Windows, MacOS, or Linux distro and view the shortcuts registered in the top menu typically found on the top of an application's screen on all OS (Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu(Linux), etc).

Here's an example of Visual Studio on Windows:

[image: File Menu in Visual Studio on Windows]

Here's an example of Open Office Writer on Ubuntu:

[image: View Menu in Open Office Writer on Ubuntu]

Below are the closest alternatives I've found, in which many support system-level keyboard shortcuts instead of application-specific keyboard shortcuts.

- Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378037/how-can-i-quickly-see-a-list-of-the-keyboard-shortcuts
- MacOS: https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/
- Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/shortcut-guide
- Program Specific: https://shortcuts.design/ or various cheatsheets online

Is there a cross-platform standalone program or OS-specific utility that currently does this?

If not, are there OS-specific APIs available on each platform to create a program that does this similar to MacOS's CheatSheet?